# How do I make xctk:IntegerUpDown accept digits only?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm trying to make a [`xctk:IntegerUpDown`](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=IntegerUpDown&referringTitle=NumericUpDown) accepts only digits. To be honest, I was surprised why a numeric control would accepts non-digits. If anyone know the actual reason for this, please tell me.

So I've tried to:
`FormatString` to `N` and `ParsingNumberStyle` to `Integer` but it still accepts non-digit chars such as letters. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `PreviewKeyDown` event. I add an example with a `TextBox` that should work for your `NumericUpDown` as well.

xaml:

```
<TextBox PreviewKeyDown="OnPreviewKeyDown" />
```

cs:

```
public void OnPreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs args)
{
    switch (args.Key) {
        case Key.D0: case Key.NumPad0: 
        case Key.D1: case Key.NumPad1: 
        case Key.D2: case Key.NumPad2: 
        case Key.D3: case Key.NumPad3: 
        case Key.D4: case Key.NumPad4: 
        case Key.D5: case Key.NumPad5: 
        case Key.D6: case Key.NumPad6: 
        case Key.D7: case Key.NumPad7: 
        case Key.D8: case Key.NumPad8: 
        case Key.D9: case Key.NumPad9:
            args.Handled = false; 
            break;
        default:
            args.Handled = true;
            break;
    }
}
```